# Receiving garbage data from specific URL using libcurl

Tags: c, macos, encoding, libcurl

I am trying to fetch HTML from a URL using libcurl. The code below has worked on every site I have tried except [this one](http://mangafox.me/manga/waltz/v01/c001/1.html).

The output from that site looks like this:

> �[ks�ƒ��T�?��MH�D��C�D�.ˏ8weGe)�M%Y

I'm using Clang on OS X

## C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;  // Curl Handle
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode result;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
        "http://mangafox.me/manga/waltz/v01/c001/1.html");
    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site is sending its response compressed with gzip -- you can tell that by looking at the headers on the reply -- they include:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.  You have to add  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); after the first  curl_easy_setopt

Comment: The official option name is CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING and the documentation is here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html